# How can I force child class to implment method that only takes child of same type as parameter?

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

is it possible that a parent class can force child classes to implement a method, that only takes objects of the same child class as parameter?

Should work like that:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void MakeLove(Animal partner);
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void MakeLove(Dog partner)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    public override void MakeLove(Fish partner)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So I don't want a dog to make love with a fish but only with other dogs...

Comment: Maybe use generics?

Comment: lol MakeLove should probably be Mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider making `Animal` generic.

```
public class Animal<T>
  where T: Animal<T>
{
    ...
    public abstract MakeLove(T partner);
    ...
}

public class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{
    ...
    public override MakeLove( Dog partner)
    ...
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only way to go.

Comment: Looks quite good so far! Thanks.   Addon question:   Is it possible to make the Animal not abstract? so that I can have objects of that class.  E.g. can I declare a property   ´´´public Animal BestFriend {get;set;}´´´  inside Animal? ( so that all Animals can have another animal as friend regardless of its type)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  You can write `class Cat : Animal<Dog>{}`, violating the requirements of the question.

Comment: Yes, this isn't an answer as it doesn't stop the issue the OP is asking about.

Answer (score -1):

You can use generics. Example:

```
public class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    public abstract MakeLove(T partner);
}

public class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{
    public override MakeLove(Dog partner)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also use casting. Example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public abstract MakeLove(Animal partner);
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override MakeLove(Animal partner)
    {
        var dogPartner = partner as Dog; // or (Dog)partner;
        ...
    }
}
```

But I would not recommend casting; it does not guarantee that the `partner` parameter is a `Dog` type.

Also, `BreedWith(Animal otherAnimal)` is more appropriate. Most animals do not "make love".

Comment: This isn't an answer as it doesn't stop the issue the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Enigmativity I disagree. It's an alternative solution.

Comment: The OP clearly said "I don't want a dog to make love with a fish but only with other dogs". Your code does not prevent `class Dog : Animal<Fish>`. The casting approach does not show how to prevent dogs and fish mating.

Comment: @Enigmativity, that does not make much sense. Implementing a generic class, such as `Dog : Animal<Dog>` is the same like creating a base class `public abstract class DogBase` with a abstract method that accepts a `Dog` parameter. Inheriting `Dog : Animal<Fish>` makes as much sense as inheriting `Dog : FishBase`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It doesn't make sense to implement `Dog : Animal<Fish>` and that's exactly what the OP is trying to avoid. They want to avoid someone writing nonsensical code.